# Matplotlibで、たくさんの列データから必要な複数データを選択してを一つのグラフに一度に描画する賢い方法

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, numpy

たとえば、`df.shape = (200, 1000)`のpandasデータがあるとします。

下記のようなグラフを描写したいのです。

横軸：行(200)
縦軸：データの範囲
グラフ種類：折れ線
ライン数：1000

1000の列データ（各200行）を一度に指定してグラフにプロットする場合、
どのようにするとシンプルにできますか？

今までは、下記のように直接指定して描いておりましたが、

```
index = df.index
col1 =d_real[1]
col2 =d_real[2]

ax.plot(index,col1)
ax.plot(index,col2)
```

1000列ともなると、とても直接書けません。
`--.plot()`の中にまとめて変数を与える方法があれば、教えてください。

追記：質問内容に追加です。
最終的は、必要なデータのみを表示できるようにしたいです。
ですので、列番番号で指定できる方法を望んでいます。
〇〇番〜△△番まで等。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単に

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,100,(200,1000)))
df.plot(legend=False)
plt.show()
```

では駄目なのでしょうか？

---

**追記（列を選択する例**）

50～54列を表示

```
df.iloc[:,50:55].plot(legend=False)
```

60列と80列と100列のみ表示

```
df.iloc[:,[60,80,100]].plot(legend=False)
```

---

**追記２（グラフ設定例）**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

N=100
rad = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'rad': rad, 'sin': np.sin(rad), 'cos': np.cos(rad)})

# SeabornのデフォルトStyleを使用
sns.set()
# グラフのサイズを設定
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# DataFrameのPlotを使用する
df.plot(x='rad', y=['sin','cos'], ax=ax,
        linestyle='dashed', #線種
        color=['darkgreen', 'darkblue'], #色
        linewidth = 0.5 #線の幅
)
# TITLEを設定
ax.set_title("TEST")
# X軸の範囲
ax.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi)
# Y軸の範囲
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
# X軸のTick（目盛）の位置を設定
ax.set_xticks([0, np.pi, np.pi*2])
# X軸のTick（目盛）の表記を設定
ax.set_xticklabels([0, 'π', '2π'])
# Y軸のTick（目盛）の位置を設定
ax.set_yticks([-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1])
# X軸のラベルを設定
ax.set_label('X [rad]')
# グラフ表示
plt.show()
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。最終的には、それら多数のデータの中から、指定したもののみ描写するようにしたいのです。pandasの.plotでは、そのような細かな設定ができないですよね？とりあえず全体を把握するには便利ですが。

Comment: それくらいなら pandasの Indexingでどうにでもなるのではないでしょうか？
一応回答に方法を追記しておきました

Comment: ありがとうございました。勉強になりました。pandasの.plotグラフはカスタマイズできないので、遠ざけておりました。同じような事をするにあたり、ラベルや線等の見栄えを細かく設定したい場合、pandasのplotではできないですよね？

Comment: プレゼン等に用いるためにグラフの見栄え等を詳細設定したい場合は、どうしたらいいでしょうか？

Comment: 見栄えであれば、seaborn の Style を使うのが簡単ではないでしょうかね。
http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html#aesthetics-tutorial

Comment: 見栄えを美しくも大事なのですが、一番の目的は、線種、線太さ、グラフの枠やメモリ線等を細かくカスタマイズしたいのです。そうなると、#matplotlib.pyplotでの作図の方がいいのでしょうかね？

Comment: 作成されるグラフのサイズやメモリ範囲も自動ではなく、設定したいです。

Comment: その手の設定であれば、DataFrame.plot() を使おうが matplotlib.pyplot を使おうがほとんど関係ありません。(pandasはmatplotlibをWrapしているだけなので)

Comment: とりあえずDataFrame.plot() を使って、グラフサイズ・線種・線サイズ・線色・タイトル・目盛り位置・目盛り表記・ラベルを設定したサンプルを書きました。（SeabornのStyleを使用）

Comment: これ以上はココに書くにはあまりにも範囲が広すぎる内容となりますので、とりあえずは自分で色々と試してみて、わからないことがありましたら新しく質問を投げてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。pandasのplotでもいろいろカスタマイズできる事が理解できました。