# DataFrame.plot() で作図した場合のax.set_label()について質問です。デフォルト表示のラベルを上書きできない・・

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[先日の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49063/19110)で頂いたDataFrame.plot() で作図した下記のプログラム(magichanさん、ありがとうございました)について、質問です。

```
ax.set_title("TEST")
ax.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.set_xticks([0, np.pi, np.pi*2])
ax.set_xticklabels([0, 'π', '2π'])
ax.set_yticks([-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1])
```

以上については、DataFrame.plot()で自動で表示される内容が上記の設定内容で上書きされます（変更できます）。

ですが、次の
ax.set_label('X [RAD]')
だけは、RAD（わざと大文字にしました）が、上書きされません。
どうすれば、任意のラベルタイトルに変更できますでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

N=100
rad = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'rad': rad, 'sin': np.sin(rad), 'cos': np.cos(rad)})

# SeabornのデフォルトStyleを使用
sns.set()
# グラフのサイズを設定
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# DataFrameのPlotを使用する
df.plot(x='rad', y=['sin','cos'], ax=ax,
        linestyle='dashed', #線種
        color=['darkgreen', 'darkblue'], #色
        linewidth = 0.5 #線の幅
)
# TITLEを設定
ax.set_title("TEST")
# X軸の範囲
ax.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi)
# Y軸の範囲
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
# X軸のTick（目盛）の位置を設定
ax.set_xticks([0, np.pi, np.pi*2])
# X軸のTick（目盛）の表記を設定
ax.set_xticklabels([0, 'π', '2π'])
# Y軸のTick（目盛）の位置を設定
ax.set_yticks([-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1])
# X軸のラベルを設定
ax.set_label('X [RAD]')
# グラフ表示
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`set_xlabel()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html) を使って下さい。

```
ax.set_xlabel('X [RAD]')
```

[`set_label()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_label.html) は凡例に使うためのラベル名を設定するメソッドであり、軸ラベルを設定するものではありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。先ほど自分で気づきました。失礼しました。

Comment: スミマセン。もともとは私のサンプルコードのタイポが原因ですね・・。気をつけます。

Comment: magichanさん、とんでもございません。引き続きよろしくお願いします。